# NGINX sef urls error: No input file specified

Tags: nginx

I've been struggling with a NGINX configuration. I've set up a development environment (local laptop) with a configuration supporting search engine friendly (SEF) urls, but the same configuration doesn't seem to work on my test server.

local configuration:

```
server {
    server_name  example;

    root   /home/arciitek/git/example/public;

    client_max_body_size 500M;


    location /collection/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php$args;
    index index.php;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/arciitek/git/example/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

This works fine. Now on the test environment it looks like this:

```
{
    server_name dev.example.com;

    access_log /srv/www/dev.example.com/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/dev.example.com/error.log debug;
    root /srv/www/dev.example.com/public;

    location /collection/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /collection/index.php$args;
    index index.php;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/dev.example.com/public$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

On my development environment everything is fine. But on my test environment, when I call a url in my browser with prettyness added : collection/[brand]/[product]. I get the: `No input file specified` error. Mind you, if I call a url anding with collection/ everyting works as well..

Can anyone help me with this please? if more info is needed, please let me know..

kind regards,

Erik

Comment: Have you missed slash in `SCRIPT_FILENAME`?

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your response. I've tried both with and without the slash, but it doesn't seem to make a difference... I've also tried $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After frustrating for a long time, I noticed that it was not the configuration that gave me trouble, but the link to sites-enabled...

There you go... *pads himself on the back...